# ¿Cómo puedo evitar que me redireccione si el login no es correcto?

Tags: php, sql, ajax, login

Tengo mi login listo, lo único que sucede es que al ingresar los credenciales incorrectos, también me redirecciona y esto no debería pasar. ¿Que me faltaría agregar al código?

Código de `AJAX`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //LOGIN
    var login = $("#login");
    login.bind("submit", function(){

        var formData = new FormData($("#login")[0]);

            $.ajax({
                url: login.attr("action"),
                type: login.attr("method"),
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $("#success-login").html("Iniciando Sesión...");
                },
                success: function(result){
                    $("#success-login").html(result);
                    $("#success-login").fadeIn("slow");
                    $("#success-login").delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
                    setTimeout("location.href = 'index.php'", 3000);
                }
            });

        return false;
    });
 });
```

Comment: No se que tienes en el html, pero un error común es no prevenir las acciones por defecto, que en tu caso es un _sumbit_, la cual refresca la pagina. Prueba con preventDefault() en tu acción click donde dispares el submit. Te dejo doc de jQuery para submit -> https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: @RafaelM Cuando usas jQuery, que la función devuelva true es el equivalente a hacer un preventDefault

Comment: @PabloLozano no entiendo bien lo que me quieres trasmitir, pero aún así en su caso, siempre devuelve false, seguramente incluso antes de saber si la llamada asíncrona ha tenido resultado.

Comment: El usuario hace submit, la función hace la llamada AJAX y cancela el submit. La respuesta a la llamada se ejecutará en un futuro y hace un `location.href = ...`. Creo que el problema es que aunque el login falle, se está ejecutando la función `success`

Answer (score 2):

Intenta hacerlo así:

```
var login = $("#login");
login.on("submit", function(event){

    event.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData($("#login")[0]);

        $.ajax({
            url: login.attr("action"),
            type: login.attr("method"),
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function() {
                $("#success-login").html("Iniciando Sesión...");
            },
            success: function(result){
                $("#success-login").html(result);
                $("#success-login").fadeIn("slow");
                $("#success-login").delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
                setTimeout("location.href = 'index.php'", 3000);
            }
        });

    return false;
});
```

Inicialmente quitamos la función document ready y ligamos el id del formulario a un evento submit, cuando en el formulario des clic en enviar se prevendrá la acción normal, que es redirigir a lo que tengas en el atributo `action` del formulario y se ejecutará todo lo de tu ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes poner un condicional dentro de success de la forma;

```
success : function(data) {

              if(data==1) { // éxito por tanto redirecciona
                $("#success-login").html(result);
                $("#success-login").fadeIn("slow");
                $("#success-login").delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
                setTimeout("location.href = 'index.php'", 3000);
              } else { // fallo por lo tanto mandas a la página del login un mensaje de advertencia 
               //alert(data);
                $("#result").html("<div class='alert alert-dismissible alert-danger'><button type='button' class='close' data-dimiss='alert'>$times;</button><strong>¡Error!</strong>Las credenciales son incorrectas</div>");
              }
          }
```